# convergence interval

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> I want to find the convergence interval of the series
> $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n}n!}{n^{n}},|x|\neq e$

i managed to show that the series will be absolutely convergent for $|x|<e$ therefore converge.

i also managed to show that the series diverges for  $x>e$ using the ratio test . i don't know how to show divergence for $x<-e$.

i read the other questions posted for that series, but none had the explanation of the divergence.

Comment: The ratio test is able to consider the absolute value of ratios; it shows that if $|x|\lt e$, the series converges, and if $|x|\gt e$, the series diverges - which includes $x\lt-e$

Comment: @FShrike but dosnt it mean the the series may conditionally converge for $x<-e$ ?

Comment: The ratio test strictly gives divergence if the limit is greater than $1$, because if the limit is greater than $1$, the terms do not tend to zero, therefore they cannot converge

Comment: @FShrike Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've obtained that the series diverges when $\lvert x\rvert>e$.

As @Fshrike suggested, it includes the case of $x<-e$.

Still, you can show the divergence separately, using the Leibniz test for alternating series:

1. When $x=-e$, the series of absolute values diverges, as follows from your prior results
2. The limit:
   $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(-e)^n\cdot n!}{n^n}\approx \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{2\pi n}\frac{n^n}{e^n}(-e)^n}{n^n}=\infty\neq 0\quad(\text{Stirling's approximation})$$
   so, the series diverges.

Comment: sadly i haven't learnt Stiriling's approximation yet.

Comment: You can simply argue that in your series $\sum u_n$ $u_n$ increases as n increases, which you should have obtained from the ratio test. FShrike has already explained it, as I can see.

Comment: Welcome pieinthesky. You should use backslashes in MathJax to obtain almost any expression; e.g. `$\lim$` renders as $\lim$

Comment: @FShrike, thanks, I'm trying to keep this in mind.

Comment: And also `$\text{Stirling's Approximation}$` also helps :)